# cant get the product from the id i sent , im store my products in localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, local-storage

im dispaching my id to the productsSlice , and from there im call to getProductById() that in my productService, the productService communicate with async-storage-service and i think the problem comes from here.
i want to get the product from the id i sent.
i dont have an error in the console.

```
//ProductDetails.jsx

export function ProductDetails() {

  let [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  // let [color, setColor] = useState("#ffffff");

  const { id } = useParams();
  console.log(id);

  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProduct(id))
  }, [id, product]);
```

```
//productsSlice.js

const productsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'products',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        getProduct: (state, action) => {
            productsService.getProductById(action.payload)
            
        }
    },
```

```
//products-service.js

async function query() {
        const response = await axios.get('https://dummyjson.com/products')
        const products = await response.data
        localStorage.setItem(PRODUCTS_KEY, JSON.stringify(products.products))
        return products
}

async function getProductById(id) {
      return storageService.get(PRODUCTS_KEY, id)
}
```

```
//async-storage-service.js

export const storageService = {
    query,
    get,
    post,
    put,
    remove,
    postMany
}

function query(entityType) {
    var entities = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(entityType)) || []
    return Promise.resolve(entities);
}

function get(entityType, entityId) {
    return query(entityType)
        .then(entities => entities.find(entity => entity.id === entityId))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux reducer functions are to be considered pure, synchronous functions. Your  `getProduct` action is calling asynchronous code ***and*** it doesn't update any state.

Convert `getProduct` to an asynchronous action and specify an `extraReducers` reducer function to handle the fulfilled Promise returned by it.

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const getProduct = createAsyncThunk(
  "/products/getProduct",
  async (id, thunkAPI) => {
    return productsService.getProductById(id);
  },
);

const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'products',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    ...
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(getProduct.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.product = action.payload; // * Note
      });
  },
};
```

****Note:** You didn't include what `initialState` is so we've no way of knowing what state should actually be updated, but it's just a normal Redux state update from here. Tweak this part to fit your actual use case.*